# Apache Kafka - KStream with KStream Join latest messages

Tags: join, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have created to KStreams that I want to join them together. The output of the two streams are the following:

**Stream 1:**

```
2    {"CODE":"AAAA96","STATUS":"SUBMITTED","ID":2}
```

**Stream 2:**

```
26   {"DESCRIPTION":"blah blah blah","QUANTITY":1,"ID_CUSTOMER_ORDER":"GR0100926","ID":26}
```

I want to create a joined stream (inner join) of this two Streams, so I have created the following KStream:

```
KStream<String, String> s_joined = s_order
        .join(s_order_item, (left,right) -> left + right,
                JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30)))
        .mapValues(value -> {
            String[] arrOfstr = value.split("(?<=})");
            JSONObject jl = new JSONObject(arrOfstr[0]);
            JSONObject jr = new JSONObject(arrOfstr[1]);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            Iterator<String> keys = jl.keys();
            while(keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                json.put(key, jl.get(key));
            }
            keys = jr.keys();
            while(keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                json.put(key, jr.get(key));
            }
            return json.toString();
        });
```

In this KStream I just use a join and I am changing the format of the output message, nothing more.

Through one example I will explain what I want to do:

The following messages are published inside the window:

**Stream 1**

```
9 {"CODE":"AAAA98","STATUS":"CANCELED","ID":"9"}
```

**Stream 2**

```
9 {"DESCRIPTION":"blah blah blah","QUANTITY":3,"ID_CUSTOMER_ORDER":"GR0100121","ID":"9"}
9 {"DESCRIPTION":"blah blah blah","QUANTITY":0,"ID_CUSTOMER_ORDER":"GR0100480","ID":"9"}
9 {"DESCRIPTION":"blah blah blah","QUANTITY":1,"ID_CUSTOMER_ORDER":"GR0100606","ID":"9"}
9 {"DESCRIPTION":"blah blah blah","QUANTITY":7,"ID_CUSTOMER_ORDER":"GR0100339","ID":"9"}
9 {"DESCRIPTION":"blah blah blah","QUANTITY":6,"ID_CUSTOMER_ORDER":"GR0100911","ID":"9"}
```

**Joined Stream**

**What is published**

```
9 {"CODE":"AAAA98","STATUS":"CANCELED","DESCRIPTION":"blah blah blah","QUANTITY":3,"ID_CUSTOMER_ORDER":"GR0100121","ID":"9"}
9 {"CODE":"AAAA98","STATUS":"CANCELED","DESCRIPTION":"blah blah blah","QUANTITY":0,"ID_CUSTOMER_ORDER":"GR0100480","ID":"9"}
9 {"CODE":"AAAA98","STATUS":"CANCELED","DESCRIPTION":"blah blah blah","QUANTITY":1,"ID_CUSTOMER_ORDER":"GR0100606","ID":"9"}
9 {"CODE":"AAAA98","STATUS":"CANCELED","DESCRIPTION":"blah blah blah","QUANTITY":7,"ID_CUSTOMER_ORDER":"GR0100339","ID":"9"}
9 {"CODE":"AAAA98","STATUS":"CANCELED","DESCRIPTION":"blah blah blah","QUANTITY":6,"ID_CUSTOMER_ORDER":"GR0100911","ID":"9"}
```

**What I want to be published**

```
9 {"CODE":"AAAA98","STATUS":"CANCELED","DESCRIPTION":"blah blah blah","QUANTITY":6,"ID_CUSTOMER_ORDER":"GR0100911","ID":"9"}
```

In conclusion, I want to publish just the latest message inside the window, not all of them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The way to achive what I want to do is use the function `suppress`. In more detail, you `groupByKey()` the KStream and then use a `Window` function. Lastly, aggregate the grouped data and use `suppress`.

```
s_joined.toStream()
        .groupByKey()
        .WindowedBy(...)
        .aggregate(...)
        .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `groupByKey` function which returns `KGroupedStream` and then transform it in a required way with `map/reduce` functions for that. Please, see [Kafka Streams DSL](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#stateless-transformations) for more info.